# Creating custom menus with Eclipse e4 (using Application.e4xmi file) is not getting displayed during product launch (in debug mode)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-emf, emf, xmi

I've created a new 'Eclipse 4 Application Project' using Luna and I created custom menu(s) using this 'Application.e4xmi' file. Also I've added a Handler Class that will be triggered when my custom menu is clicked (all these stuffs have been specified in the Application.e4xmi).

With this setup If I launch my product (as an Eclipse product) in debug mode, I'm not able to see my custom menus and also If I try to export as a product and trying to launch the eclipse product I'm running into problems.

xmi contents include :

```
<application:Application xmi:version="2.0"  xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:application="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/application" xmlns:basic="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/application/ui/basic" xmlns:menu="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/application/ui/menu" xmi:id="_hHQuoFh2EeWNzdEqyCDxmA" elementId="org.eclipse.e4.ide.application" bindingContexts="_hHQuqVh2EeWNzdEqyCDxmA">
  <children xsi:type="basic:TrimmedWindow" xmi:id="_hHQuoVh2EeWNzdEqyCDxmA" label="com.ami.test.e4project" width="500" height="400"/>
  <handlers xmi:id="_6WD5YFh2EeWNzdEqyCDxmA" elementId="com.ami.test.e4project.handler.0" contributionURI="bundleclass://com.ami.test.e4project/com.ami.test.e4project.HandlerImplementation" command="_3T-ocFh2EeWNzdEqyCDxmA"/>
  <rootContext xmi:id="_hHQuqVh2EeWNzdEqyCDxmA" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialogAndWindow" name="In Dialog and Windows">
    <children xmi:id="_hHQuqlh2EeWNzdEqyCDxmA" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window" name="In Windows"/>
    <children xmi:id="_hHQuq1h2EeWNzdEqyCDxmA" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialog" name="In Dialogs"/>
  </rootContext>
  <menuContributions xmi:id="_s3SAEFh2EeWNzdEqyCDxmA" elementId="com.ami.test.e4project.menucontribution.0" parentId="org.eclipse.e4.legacy.ide.application">
    <children xsi:type="menu:Menu" xmi:id="_z21zMFh2EeWNzdEqyCDxmA" elementId="com.ami.test.e4project.menu.filee" label="Filee">
      <children xsi:type="menu:HandledMenuItem" xmi:id="_0PiAAFh2EeWNzdEqyCDxmA" elementId="com.ami.test.e4project.handledmenuitem.new" label="New" command="_3T-ocFh2EeWNzdEqyCDxmA"/>
    </children>
  </menuContributions>
  <commands xmi:id="_3T-ocFh2EeWNzdEqyCDxmA" elementId="com.ami.test.e4project.command.command" commandName="command"/>
  <addons xmi:id="_hHQuolh2EeWNzdEqyCDxmA" elementId="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.service" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.core.commands/org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.CommandServiceAddon"/>
  <addons xmi:id="_hHQuo1h2EeWNzdEqyCDxmA" elementId="org.eclipse.e4.ui.contexts.service" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.services/org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.ContextServiceAddon"/>
  <addons xmi:id="_hHQupFh2EeWNzdEqyCDxmA" elementId="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.service" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings/org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.BindingServiceAddon"/>
  <addons xmi:id="_hHQupVh2EeWNzdEqyCDxmA" elementId="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.commands.model" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.CommandProcessingAddon"/>
  <addons xmi:id="_hHQuplh2EeWNzdEqyCDxmA" el ementId="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.handler.model" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon"/>
  <addons xmi:id="_hHQup1h2EeWNzdEqyCDxmA" elementId="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.contexts.model" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.ContextProcessingAddon"/>
  <addons xmi:id="_hHQuqFh2EeWNzdEqyCDxmA" elementId="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.bindings.model" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon"/>
</application:Application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using menu contributions to a menu that does not exist (`org.eclipse.e4.legacy.ide.application`).

When you create an e4 application using the Application.e4xmi there are **no** predefined menus or anything else. You must define the menus you want. Add a 'Main Menu' child to your 'Trimmed Window' and put the menu items there.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've made a mistake by contributing my custom menu with the wrong ID ("org.eclipse.e4.legacy.ide.application"). 
The posted answer works for me. Thanks!!

Comment: Greg-449 : I have one question, If I Add a 'Main Menu' child to my Trimmed Window, then the entire RCP Application  look itself got changed to a Trimmed Window. I do not want in this way, already I have a RCP application (based on 3.7 RCP) with all the necessary views and menus configured. I'm now switching to e4 Architecture. 
Here I just need to replace these existing menus (3.7 RCP menus) with my own set of 'New Menus' (using e4).
Is it possible to achieve this with Application.e4xmi file ?

Comment: No, e4 is completely different to 3.x compatibility mode. A lot of 3.x code will not work in a pure e4 application. e4 is intended for applications which don't use any 'org.eclipse.ui.xxx' plugins or resources such as 'IFile'. If  you want to use those stick to a 3.x RCP.

Comment: Greg-449 : I migrated my 3.x code to build in e4 Environment (by resolving all the errors that incurred during the migration process). Previously (in 3.7 code) we had created menus manually.   I came to know that e4 introduces 'Application Modelling Framework' through which we can introduce menus, toolbars with relatively less code intervention. 
So my intention is to remove the codes that I used previously for menu creations (in 3.7) and I would like to have these menus having defined in the "Application.e4xmi" file.  So you mean to say that this idea will not work ?   - just curious to know

Comment: It is hard work to convert a 3.x RCP to a 'pure' e4 application because none of the 'org.eclipse.ui.xxx' extension points and plugins can be used. So all views, editors, ... have to be reworked. Eclipse 4 still supports 3.x style RCPs. But I am not clear what you really want to do and this is far too big an area for comments (and is not suitable for Stack Overflow questions).

Comment: Thanks Greg for your valuable information.... I understand that migration from Eclipse 3.x to e4 has some complexities associated with it. 
But still, I would like to switch from 3.x to e4. The reason is, I want to gain access of the new features (like Dependency Injection) that eclipse introduced in its e4 series. So is there any steps ( or tutorial) that would help me in achieving this migration (despite these difficulties). Or is it possible to have access to e4 features in 3.x series (which I believe that is not possible in 3.x mode)  - Just a clarification.

Comment: I don't know of any guides but I haven't really looked. Some people seem to be trying various sorts of mixed apps but again I have not looked at them.

Comment: Once again Thanks :)  A Final question, you've indicated that "It is hard work  to convert a 3.x RCP to a 'pure' e4 application because none of the org.eclipse.ui.xxx extension points and plugins can be reused. So all view, editors,...have to be reworked". Can I have a list of such deprecated (or API's which is active in 3.x RCP and not in e4).  So that it will be very helpful for me (or at-least before performing the actual switch I would be knowing the list of API's that are not supported in Eclipse e4 series.).